# Just out of curiosity. What's this curvature per unit length for a sphere? I see a lot of flat earthers using it.

Tags: earth

I've seen most flat earthers mention if earth was a sphere the earth should curve at x value per unit length. Is that even a proper logic? Radius of curvature is constant for sphere and a circle of a particular radius. If that logic exist can anyone share a simple diagram? I just can't comprehend how they got to that logic. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1896238/how-to-calculate-curvature-of-earth-per-surface-kilometer